# Discover the Node version in projects

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I have some projects (web applications, APIs, libraries) created with NodeJs.

These projects are in Gitlab repositories.

My need is to find out which version of Node these projects run on.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: you will be able to check the versions of the npm packages installed in your "packages.json" and thus be able to trace the nodejs version with which the project was developed, or if there is an "engines" key in the "packages.json"

Comment: NodeJS attempts to be backwards compatible with every new major version. You could potentially try running the project on the latest nodejs stable version. If your app isn't running on the latest version, you could do a binary search on the nodejs versions to find the latest compatible version ([nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) might help)

Comment: "*These projects are in Gitlab repositories.*" - I don't see how that matters. Instead, please tell us how and where these projects are running/used, and in how many instances of the respective application.

Comment: Hello, @Bergi, I'll explain to you why I added this information that you didn't understand. Just add this detail to the question and see if anyone knows of a hack for this tool that makes the search easier.

Comment: @BrunoDMota What tool are you talking about?

Comment: @BrunoDMota You don't seem to understand. One and the same JavaScript code can be run under multiple different versions of node.js. A library in particular can be used in many different applications, each application running in different environments. Just looking at the source code won't tell you anything. You need to look at the command that actually executes the code, at each concrete application process.

Comment: @BrunoDMota Unless you [edit] your question to share more details, in particular what you mean by "project" (e.g. containing docker files that are used to containerise the code to run), the answer will be that this is **impossible**.